# How to calculate force from source on a wall?

Tags: physics, fluid-dynamics

I've got the following question I'm trying to answer, however I'm just not really sure where to start. I assume I need to find the pressure on the plate and then integrate over area to find the force, but I'm just not sure how to begin and couldn't find anything relevant through searching on Google etc. to help give me a start.

Thanks.

**Question:**

A line source of strength 2πm is located a distance a above a horizontal
plate that extends infinitely in both horizontal directions. Find
the force per unit width on the plate, ignoring gravity and taking the
pressure below the plate to be uniform and equal to the stagnation
pressure of the fluid. (You may find the substitution x = a tan θ useful
in evaluating any integrals which may arise)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many [users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201/148510), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please edit the question.

Comment: The description of the configuration is ambiguous.  Is this potential flow or otherwise? Why is the pressure "below" an infinite plate relevant if the fluid is above?  How would you solve the problem with a line source and no plate?